# Парсинг погоды с Yahoo

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser, weather, yahoo

Хочу распарсить xml погоду или json с сайта
https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Но никак не могу извлечь информацию из XML. Потому что информация находится в атрибутах, например тут
[xml для Москвы](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22moscow%2C%20russia%22)&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys) 
Температура находится в атрибутах `high="75"` - например

и при этом в теге встречается двоеточие `yweather:forecast`а php пишет ошибку если стоит двоеточие.

Вообще не представляю как вывести, например, погоду на завтра.

Comment: код как пробуете?

Comment: JSON ;)  `&format=xml` -> `&format=json`